# Passing a value from views.py to template html in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm having trouble displaying a value calculated by a function in views.py. Currently my code basically functions as such: It has two forms, each taking in user input. In views.py, it handles it basically as

```
if first form is submitted:
    generate a value games
    return render_template('base.html', games=games)
elif second form is submitted:
    generate a value games
    return render_template('base.html', games=games)
return render_template('login.html', firstform=firstform, secondform=secondform)
```

where login.html is a template that extends base.html. In base.html, I have

```
{% if games %}
  <h1> {{ games }} </h1>
{% endif %}
```

the idea being that the value of games calculated in views.py would then be displayed. Upon submitting the form however, no value is displayed. Any idea for where I might be going wrong?

Comment: whats the exact output on your page? is it hitting the `if games` condition in the first place?

Comment: none at all. It's as if the form was not submitted at all, although I can tell it was because I can see the code that generates the value meant to be displayed running. I assume it hits the if games condition, because all the html after it executes fine.

Comment: try to make a different simple `html` page and see if you can have the correct output in it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want two different routes, one for each form to POST data to. For example,

```
@app.route("/my/app/form1", methods=["POST"])
def handle_form1_submit():
    ...

@app.route("/my/app/form2", methods=["POST"])
def handle_form2_submit():
    ...
```

Then change the `action=""` attribute of each form accordingly.

Even a better approach is to have one route, and instead of form post, ajax that route and update the page dynamically.

Comment: The second approach is definitely what I would want, but I have next to no experience with ajax. Is there a reference for doing this?

Comment: Try spending a little bit of time learning ajax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp). Plenty of online resource for learning this sort of stuff.